# Edit CSV not-spatial table in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, csv, delete

I am trying to edit a not-spatial CSV table in PyQGIS 2.18 (i.e. deleting existing fields and adding new one ) for the first time (I can do it with polygonal vector layers but I guess something is different). I just wrote the script below but it doesn't work (i.e. it does not delete fields and returns false when starting editing). I also tried to see the files of editablegeocsv plugin, as suggested in another post by underdark, but I am a beginner and I did not understand it. PS: I cannot try with last Python / QGIS releases.

```
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    import processing, math, numpy, csv


    uri= "file:///D:/.../PROVA.csv?delimiter=,"
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'name', 'delimitedtext')
    if layer.isValid() is True:
        print "OK!!"
    else:
        print "NOT VALID!"#it returns "OK!!"
     

    caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteAttributes:
        res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([0,1,7])
    layer.updateFields() #it neither does return any message nor delete any column
    
    #and then,
    layer.startEditing() #it returns "False"
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("NewField",QVariant.Int)])
    layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have spacial data, your file cant be considered a layer.

You dont need qgis at all. Use only python.

This aproach is for python3. Not sure if it works with python2.

```
import csv

result_list = []

# 1. read file
with open('/path/to/file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for row in reader:
        # 2. modify values
        # append only the "columns" you need
        # you dont need 0, 1 and 7
        # so we create a new list without those indexes
        # first from index 2 to "7"(not included in range so really is 2-6)
        # the second range is from index 8 to the end. Only needed if you have more than 7 columns
        result_list.append(row[2:7] + row[8:])

# 3. write file
with open('/path/to/result_file.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(result_list)
```

Comment: Thank you! but how can I do the part you wrote in grey (e.g. modify values and append only columns)?

Comment: that its done in the line `result_list.append(row[2:7] + row[8:])`. I just numerated the steps to do. 1. read file, 2. modify values and 3. write file.